# PHP: Dynamically create a simple array without indexes

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I know all the arrays have indexes, but here's a problem that many of you may have faced some time in the past: I am using Yii Framework's [CDetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView) to display some data. The problem is that i don't really know what data it will be displayed (actually I do some of the data, but it needs to be dynamic, not hardcoded). The `CDetailView::attributes` parameter requires an array like this `array('name:type:label', 'name1:type:label', 'name2:type:label' ...)` to be passed. The data is retrieved from the database and, therefore, it is an associative array, which Yii doesn't handle. Thus, I would need to create this type of array `array($field1, $field2, $field3, ...)` dynamically, without the indexes. How can I do that? I tried `array_values()`, but, of course, it includes the indexes. Does any of you have an idea about this, or I should just override the Yii's class? Thank you in advance!

Comment: All arrays have indexes, whether you (or Yii) use them or not.

Comment: Yii is written in PHP. Hence if it's accepts array that array contains indexs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, the conclusion is the following:

You can't create an array that looks like this `array($item1, $item2, $item3...)` dynamically.

Regarding the Yii's issue, apparently, if you pass the associative array it will handle it, I was creating an array of an array ( `array(array(1 => $item1, 2 $item2))`), that's why it wasn't working.

Thank you anyway for your comments.